# Implementing Visitor Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns

How to add member to a hierarchy of classes without recompiling the hierarchy?
Suppose hierarchy is

```
LandTransport extends Transport
Car extends LandTransport
```

We need to add method `GetCapacity` to hierarchy. How to do this using visitor pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interface is defined in compile time so it's fixed in runtime.But you can add functionality to existing classes with visitor pattern via runtime polymorphism.

Just create two interfaces one is visitable and second visitor, pass the visitor to visitable object and calculate GetCapacity logic inside.

Example

```
class myClass;

class visitor {
virtual void handle(myClass cl);

}

class iVisitable {
 virtual void visit(visitor& v);
}



class myClass : public iVisitable{
  void visit(visitor& v){
   v.handle(this);
}
}

//Put getCapacity logic here and pass it to myClass
class getCapacityVisitor : iVisitor { } ...
```